How To Set Data with Button and Display data on HMI
I want make a program in HMI TouchWin, There is 10 Button to represent number 0 to 9, if i click the button it will show in display data, ex: if i click 4237 it will show 4237 in display data. How to make like that, can some one help me?
enter image description here
I want make a simple Calculator just with HMI

Welcome to SO. Please read How-to-ask. For a good question you should show the result of your research. What tutorial did you try and how did you fail to achieve your goal. Please edit your question to include your current code together with detailled description where you are stuck.

class MockServer :
    Server(0),
    AutoCloseable {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val ports: List<Int>
        get() = this.connectors.filterIsInstance(ServerConnector::class.java).map { it.localPort }

    val url: String
        get() = "http://localhost:${ports.first()}"

    override fun doStart() {
        super.doStart()
        logger.info("Started at $url")
    }

    override fun close() {
        if (isStarted) {
            logger.info("Stopping at $url")
            stop()
        }
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to SO. Your attempt to answer the question is appreciated. Nevertheless you should keep in mind what language the author of the question is using. The question is only tagged with C language tag. Therefore answers should also be in C. Or if there is no C API available that should be mentioned explicitely.
